# previous instance still active error in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I created app which user can start from menu and from icon. I do not use GlobalEventListener in my app, just register ApplicationMenuitem. And now I am getting error: previous instance still active when launch my app.

Steps to reproduce not so trivial:

1. launch app from icon
2. do not close it, just switch to another app
3. launch app from icon again

I founded [article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Help-with-quot-previous-instance-still-active-quot-message/td-p/402839) in blackberry's forum about it , but I can't find solution where I should remove my ApplicationMenuItem: it added on phone boot and should show all the time.

My code:

```
public class Jingu extends UiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationManager app = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while (keepGoing) {
        if (app.inStartup()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else {
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }

    Jingu theApp = new Jingu();
    theApp.initMenuItem();
    theApp.showMainScreen();
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public Jingu() {

}

public void showMainScreen() {
    showScreen(new JinguMainScreen(this));
}

public void initMenuItem() {
    // Create menu item
    Object o = RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().get(JinguMenuItem.MY_MENU_ID);
    // register only if not done already.
    if (o == null) {
        new JinguMenuItem(this).registerInstance();
    }
}



public void showScreen(Screen aScreen) {
    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {

        try {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(aScreen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(aScreen);
    }
}

}

public class JinguMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem {
public static final long MY_MENU_ID = 0xb9739d5240d5943dL;
private final Jingu jingu;

public JinguMenuItem(Jingu jingu) {
    super(0x350100);
    this.jingu = jingu;
}

public void registerInstance() {
    Object menuItem = RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().remove(MY_MENU_ID);
    if (menuItem == null) {
        ApplicationMenuItemRepository amir =                            ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance();
        amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_SYSTEM, this);
        RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().put(MY_MENU_ID, this);
    }
}


public Object run(Object context) {
    jingu.setDefaultFont(Font.getDefault());
    jingu.setMainApp(false);
    jingu.setBbmEditField(null);

    jingu.showMainScreen();

    return context;
}

public String toString() {
    return "My Menu";
}
}
```

plz advice where I should delete ApplicationMenuItem in my app?

my regards,

Vadim

Comment: As a comment to step 2: I found out that switching the application will actually close your app by default, so it's basically the same as hitting close, which also only closes the screen thus calling onClose(). You need to overwrite onClose() of your screen class to just send it into background instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this situation is:

1. create alternative entry point and run it on app load
2. register menu in it
3. do not use runtimeStore

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering an ApplicationMenuItem from your application, as a user I would consider it bad style for your application to remove and exit, even if RIM provided a way to do this. You may want to separate your application into two parts. One provides the minimal support for responding to the ApplicationMenuItem selection, that starts automatically and runs in the background. The other has all the rest and can run and exit as needed.

Comment: So I should have one instance of application always running in background?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, but not what I suggested.